# How to submit 3 forms of 3 diffrent pages at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have 3 forms in 3 different pages, and the submit button is on the 3rd page. How can I submit all 3 forms simultaneously by clicking on submit button? Is there any solution in javascript or jquery?

page-1

```
<script src="home/submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<form id="firstForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ1" value="answ1" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

page-2

```
<script src="home/submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<form id="secondForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ2" value="answ2" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ3" value="answ3" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ4" value="answ4" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

page-3

```
<script src="home/submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<form id="ThirdForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ5" value="answ5" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ6" value="answ6" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ7" value="answ7" autocomplete="off"/>
  <button id="submitt" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

in submit.js I have written

```
$(document).click("#submit",function(){
  $("#firstForm").submit();
  $("#secondForm").submit();
  $("#thirdForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: did you tried anything? can you show what you have done?

Comment: I have created one separate js file submit.js and there I have written the code,

$(document).click("#submit",function(){
 $("#firstForm").submit();
 $("#secondtForm").submit();
 $("#thirdForm").submit();
});

Comment: try to use hiden html iframe.

Comment: Put all data into the same form... If you need to send some of the data to another server, use curl

Answer (score 0):

What you are affectively trying to create here is known as a **wizard** -  a larger form that is broken down into separate sections. One common method is to use a server-side language to write the value of the first page's form fields into the second page as hidden input elements. For example:

```
<script src="home/submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<form id="secondForm">
  <!-- this is the submission from the first page, and could be generated in a server-side scripting language -->
  <input type="hidden" name="answ1" value="ANSWER" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ2" value="answ2" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ3" value="answ3" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="answ4" value="answ4" autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

I hope this helps.